# How do I condense one column of a data frame by checking another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm very new to coding so I apologize if my question is terribly worded. I have a data frame with two columns like this,

```
record        x

1             NA
1              2
1              1
2             NA
3              9
3              1
4              2
5             NA
6             4
6             NA
```

and I need to create a new data frame or matrix which has rows equal to the unique values of record, and columns which contain each value of x for that given unique value of instance (and 0 if NA), like this:

```
1   0   2   1  
2   0   0   0
3   9   1   0
4   2   0   0
5   0   0   0
6   4   0   0
```

Is there an easy way to alter the data like this?

Currently I'm trying to do this with nested for loops, with the first running a number of times equal to the number of unique values of record. I then check the total number of occurrences of that value, then try another for loop which iterates that number of times? I'm not really sure where I'm going but if there is a function or easier way to think about it I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R alternative using @JilberUrbina's data.

```r
df |>
  transform(rn = ave(rep(1L, nrow(df)), record, FUN = seq_along)) |>
  reshape(direction="wide", idvar="record", timevar="rn") |>
  lapply(\(z) if (is.numeric(z)) replace(z, is.na(z), 0) else z) |>
  as.data.frame()
#   record x.1 x.2 x.3
# 1      1   0   2   1
# 2      2   0   0   0
# 3      3   9   1   0
# 4      4   2   0   0
# 5      5   0   0   0
# 6      6   4   0   0
```

The `if (is.numeric(z))` is just a safeguard I added in case there are alternate non-numeric columns you'd be reshaping. The `as.data.frame()` is because `lapply` is going to return a `list` even though it started with a `data.frame` (which is effectively just a list).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `pivot.wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(record) %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n(),
         x = coalesce(x, 0)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = x, values_fill = 0) 
  
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   record [6]
  record   `1`   `2`   `3`
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     0     2     1
2      2     0     0     0
3      3     9     1     0
4      4     2     0     0
5      5     0     0     0
6      6     4     0     0
```

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text="record        x
1             NA
1              2
1              1
2             NA
3              9
3              1
4              2
5             NA
6             4
6             NA", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: `coalesce(.x, 0)` is a good replacement for `ifelse(..)`

Comment: @r2evans good choice!

Comment: `tidyr` also has the `replace_na()` function, which might be more explicit. You might consider adding a `library(dplyr)` to your answer so OP knows where some of the functions came from.

Answer (score 0):

Another tidyverse option:

```
df  %>%
   summarise(x = list(x), .by = record) %>%
   unnest_wider(x, names_sep = '_', transform = ~replace_na(.x, 0))

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  record   x_1   x_2   x_3
   <int> <int> <int> <int>
1      1     0     2     1
2      2     0     0     0
3      3     9     1     0
4      4     2     0     0
5      5     0     0     0
6      6     4     0     0
```